# Error: Error #2134: Cannot create SharedObject

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, shared-objects

I'm trying to setup a new project and I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Error #2134: Cannot create SharedObject.
at flash.net::SharedObject$/getLocal()
at com.google.analytics.core::Buffer()[//com/google/analytics/core/Buffer.as:198]
at com.google.analytics.components::FlexTracker/_trackerFactory()[/com/google/analytics/components/FlexTracker.as:180]
```

When I attempt to debug if I click on any of the links (to the methods in the debugger) the debugger disconnects.

Mac OSX, FB4.6

Comment: @SamDeHaan, I had similar issues using FB in linux a couple years back (before it was entirely abandoned), it seemed different versions of the debugger player made a difference at the time (using FDB at the command line yielded the same result, attempting to print a variable would cause the disconnect, in the IDE it would randomly disconnect sometimes just after app startup sometimes a minute or so in).  To get more insight does this only occur when using the google tracker or using shared objects, or does this occur even with a simple test project. You may need to file or find a bug report.

Comment: Please show the code and the version of Flash Player you're currently using.

Comment: @Shaun - I think it has to do with the Google tracker. I can create a test project just for kicks creating a shared object and see if it reacts the same way.

Comment: @J_A_X - I don't have access to the code. The source is in a SWC. I'm using, MAC 11,1,102,64 debugger.

Comment: Gotcha.  Have you tried looking at the code for [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/)? I'm wondering if there's a problem (or a change) with SharedObject between the different flash players.

Comment: There was a similar bug in the google code repository a few years ago but it was marked fixed.

Answer (score 2):

**Causes**: Shared Objects cannot have spaces in their names.
**Solution**: Remove any spaces. IE myVar.replace(/ /g, "_");

**Cause**: Another cause is setting an incorrect path. IE “./” vs “/”
**Solution**: Remove illegal character from path.

**Cause**: Possible bug when you set the localPath on local or the file system.
**Solution**: Set the local path to null when testing on localhost or the file system. SharedObject.getLocal("myData", null);

More information [here](http://www.actionscripterrors.com/?p=806).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your SWC's **Link Type** to **Merged into code**.